# Sort by elements in a list in Racket

Tags: sorting, scheme, racket

**Problem**

Just for clarification: this is not really about sorting in its precise sense. I am given a function `(sort-sym lst symbol)`. The function takes in a (listof (listof symbol)) and a symbol to turn it into a (list (listof (listof symbol)) (list (listof symbol))). Just stating the problem here does not really help that much so let's jump right in to the examples.

**Examples**

For a list

```
(define example (list 
                     (list 'chocolate 'sweet 'expensive)                          
                     (list 'crocodile 'hostile 'big 'heavy) 
                     (list 'brick 'heavy 'red) 
                     (list 'chocolate 'bitter 'dark)))
```

If I input `(sort-sym example'chocolate)`, the list will be sorted in this way:

```
(list
(list (list 'chocolate 'sweet 'expensive)
      (list 'chocolate 'bitter 'dark))

(list (list 'crocodile 'hostile 'big 'heavy)
      (list 'brick 'heavy 'red)))
```

If the input was `(sort-sym example'crocodile)`, then the list would be

```
(list
    (list (list 'crocodile 'hostile 'big 'heavy))

    (list (list 'chocolate 'sweet 'expensive)
          (list 'chocolate 'bitter 'dark)
          (list 'brick 'heavy 'red)))
```

Note that all the lists that have the word 'chocolate is put in one list, and all the lists that do not have the word is put in another list. Order does not matter in this case.

Also: the space between the 2 lists is just there to make the code more clear.

**Code**

So I'm a bit lost on this one. But I've tried a few things, for example, I tried using filter.

```
(define (sort-examples lst sym)
  (local [(define (sym-equal? other-sym) (symbol=? other-sym sym))]
    (cond [(empty? lst) empty]
          [else (cons (filter sym-equal? (first lst))
                      (sort-examples (rest lst) sym))])))
```

This doesn't really help though, since I am trying to keep the lists, not remove elements from it. Can I have some guidance on this one? Thanks.

Comment: Does racket support SRFI-1's [`partition`](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#FilteringPartitioning)? Or is writing your own version the point of the exercise?

Comment: I suspect that a point of this exercise is to discover how much easier it becomes if you divide it into two problems, "partitioning a list based on a predicate" and "defining a predicate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted in the comments, in Racket it will be a simple matter of using the `partition` built-in procedure:

```
(define (sort-sym lst sym)
  (let-values (((match no-match)
                (partition (lambda (sl) (symbol=? (first sl) sym))
                           example)))
    (list match no-match)))
```

It's also possible to solve this by doing two `filter` operations, although it'll be less efficient:

```
(define (sort-sym lst sym)
  (list (filter (lambda (sl) (symbol=? (first sl) sym)) lst)
        (filter (lambda (sl) (not (symbol=? (first sl) sym))) lst)))
```

Either way it works as expected for the given examples:

```
(define example
  '((chocolate sweet expensive)                          
    (crocodile hostile big heavy) 
    (brick heavy red) 
    (chocolate bitter dark)))

(sort-sym example 'chocolate)
=> '(((chocolate sweet expensive) (chocolate bitter dark))
     ((crocodile hostile big heavy) (brick heavy red)))

(sort-sym example 'crocodile)
=> '(((crocodile hostile big heavy))
     ((chocolate sweet expensive) (chocolate bitter dark) (brick heavy red)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This really helped. Even though I am allowed to use lambda, I am curious to know if there's another option besides it. If there is, could you briefly explain how that would work?

Comment: Well, you could basically implement your own version of `filter`: a procedure that receives an input a list, and returns as output the elements on the list that meet a condition. The general idea is, that you should split the problem into smaller parts and write helper procedures to solve each part.